# In the Ring Signature Process, which one of my keys is used for signing?

Tags: transaction-data, ring-signatures, key-image, messagesigning

I don't get the Ring Signature process. I tried to read about that but I don't understand what is happening in a more technical way.

I'm specially confused about which one of my "Public Keys" will participate in the process? Is the Transaction Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some notation: `a` and `b` being your *private* view and spend keys, `A` and `B` being your *public* view and spend keys.

> which one of my keys is used for signing?

Simplified, you sign each input ring with a *private* key *derived* from the output you own (e.g. the output you are spending) and your wallet's spend private key.

Thus, if `P = Hs(8aR|i)+B` is the output you are spending, the private key used during signing that input ring is `x = Hs(8aR|i)+b`.

> I'm specially confused about which one of my "Public Keys" will participate in the process?

Your wallet *public keys* are used by the person sending you Monero, when creating the output you'll later be able to spend. I.e. they compute your output as `P = Hs(8rA|i)+B` (which happens to be the same the same as `P = Hs(8aR|i)+B` from above).

Comment: By giving a detailed check to those calculations, I noticed that they are the same as the ones used in Stealth Addresses logic. Does this means that Ring Signature  deals with just Stealth Addresses?

Comment: A "stealth address" is just another name for a one-time output key.